# Invalid syntax using dict comprehension

Tags: python, syntax-error, dictionary-comprehension

Given a list of floats named 'x', I would like to create a dict mapping each x in x[1:-1] to it's neighbors using a dict comprehension. I have tried the following line :

```
neighbours = {x1:(x0,x2) for (x0,x1,x2) in zip(x[:-2],x[1:-1],x[2:])}
```

However, the syntax seems to be invalid. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This works for me on sample list: `[1.0,2.3,4.1,1.9,7.0,9.9]`. You need Python 2.7+ or 3.0+ to use dict/set comprehensions.

Comment: Which is your exact python version?

Comment: Worked in my [test](http://ideone.com/pfWVl).

Comment: My exact python version is "python 2.6.6 {r266:84297, Aug 24 2010, 18:46:32} [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32"

Comment: TIL about dictionary comprehensions

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[Dict comprehensions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/) are only available in Python 2.7 upwards. For earlier versions, you need the `dict()` constructor with a generator:

```
dict((x1, (x0,x2)) for (x0,x1,x2) in zip(x[:-2],x[1:-1],x[2:]))
```